# Download unpublished Google spreadsheet as CSV

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet that has not been made public, but just available to anyone that has the access link. Though I can access the data in CSV format from my browser even when I am not logged into my Google account (that is, anonymous access is allowed), there is no way I can download the data from the command line using wget, for instante. I have found several web pages with some instructions to create the download URL, but so far I've had no success. Is there an easy, straightforward way of doing this or will I have to use some Google Data library to access that data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now I can answer questions, so I will leave it answered for good (pasting from my previous comment).

My problem was that I was not storing the cookie correctly. At the time, I was using a Python program to try to download this. This fixed the problem I was reporting:

```
# Cookie management 
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar())) 
csv_data =  csv.reader(opener.open(url))
```

Answer (score 29):

Maybe I'm not correctly understanding what you're trying to do, but I found a solution [in this article](http://softwarebuzzer.com/how-to-download-shared-google-documents-spreadsheets/) that works just fine for me.

In the article, the author creates a download link for the spreadsheet as an XLS file (using "&output=xls”), but I tried "&output=csv" and successfully downloaded a correct CSV file.

Here's the download link to my "Download Test Spreadsheet", constructed just the way the author of the article suggested, but with "csv" substituted for "xls":

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv

The link is anonymous (i.e., "Anyone who has the link can view"), and I downloaded it without logging into my Google account. I'll admit that I didn't use wget to do it (I just used a browser -- I didn't have wget installed), but I can't think of a reason that wget wouldn't work just as well.

Actually, I just grabbed a copy of wget and tried it, and it downloads the file correctly too:

```
% wget --no-check-certificate --output-document=test.csv 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc&output=csv'

< bla bla bla, reams of output from wget >

% cat test.csv
Foo,Bar,Baz
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

So there ya go...

---

**UPDATING FOR 2018**

As commented by @AndyMortimer, the new *download URL*  is 
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?gid=<GID>&format=csv`  
where `<KEY>` and `<GID>` can be obtained from your *navigation's URL*, 
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/edit#gid=<GID>`

PS:  spreadsheets may have multiple workbooks, *GID* is the desired workbook ID. One-workbook-spreadsheet usually has `gid=0`, but if you add more they'll have random numbers (the *GID* is preseved even changing tab-order).

So, using `wget` and the same spreadsheet,

```
   wget --no-check-certificate -O test.csv \
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc/export?gid=0&format=csv'
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity I tried fetching the file with wget using both "&output=xls" and "&output=txt", and both of these trials worked correctly as well. (The "txt" format causes the spreadsheet to be downloaded as a tab-delimited file, which was something I wouldn't have known if I hadn't started fooling around with this. So thanks! I learned a couple of new things in this process.)

Comment: In the end, for no reasons I don't yet understand, I was not able to download the file. I could talk to the owner to make it public, so that was the end of the problem for me. Thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: Sure, no worries. I actually had no experience with any of that when I found your question -- I was trying to figure out how to do something similar at the time. So it was a good exercise for me to figure out how to do it, and much of my reason for answering was to document what I had discovered. Good that you were able to find such an effective alternate solution. :-)

Comment: Even though this question is quite old, I'm going to comment a bit.

My problem was that I was not storing the cookie correctly. At the time, I was using a Python program to try to download this. This fixed the problem I was reporting:

`# Cookie management`
`opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(CookieJar()))`
`csv_data = csv.reader(opener.open(url))`
```

Comment: The link given in this answer is the old URL format. For examples with the new URL scheme, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23394860/305913 .

Comment: Thanks, This is so helpful

Answer (score 20):

I'm able to get a `wget`-able URL from public spreadsheet URLs that look like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/edit?usp=sharing
```

by changing them to look like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/export?format=csv
```

so that my wget command would look like:

```
$ wget "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/export?format=csv"
```

Make sure you share the spreadsheet first with the blue "Share" button in the top right, then "Get Sharable Link".

Comment: to change filename with wget use: wget -O FILE URL

Comment: I want to add that the second LONG_ID_STRING doesn't seem to matter. The following URL works fine: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/export?format=csv`

Comment: This solution worked for me. @ArjunGuha is correct. The seconds `LONG_ID_STRING` is not necessary.

Comment: Edited to remove unnecessary LONG_ID_STRING

Comment: It is **not a solution** for multiple spreadsheets in same `LONG_ID_STRING`, because gets only the first spreadsheet.   **How to get the correct spreadsheet by its *gid*?**  See typical navegation URL as `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/LONG_ID_STRING/edit#gid=_ID_`.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I got a 302 error (Moved Temporarily), then it downloaded some HTML.  I think it's because I'm not authenticated.  

Is there a way to include credentials in the wget request?

Comment: this doesn't work as you have to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

To access other tabs you need to click and get the gid of that tab, so:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GxmL3bbejjGx-Ji7kzsnZLzkSaMrfX5WwgRAvvqfqpw/pubhtml?widget=true&amp%3Bheaders=false#gid=2120833204`

Becomes:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GxmL3bbejjGx-Ji7kzsnZLzkSaMrfX5WwgRAvvqfqpw/export?format=csv&id=1GxmL3bbejjGx-Ji7kzsnZLzkSaMrfX5WwgRAvvqfqpw&gid=2120833204`

Answer (score -1):

Ran into this problem and tried a few of the solutions. None were working perfectly so I wrote this curl which seems to do the job. You need to share your google spreadsheet with anyone who has the link for it to work

`curl -o /path/to/file/you/want/csv/to/go.csv 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=[the-id-of-your-spreadsheet]&output=csv' -L`

the `-L` is the trick here has google often moves the csv around but will send you a redirect link. `-L` tells `curl` to follow the redirects until it lands on the file.

you can find the `id` of your spreadsheet by opening it in google drive and looking at the url

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[idwillbehere]/edit#gid=0`

Comment: Please you must to show how to map `_BIG_BASE64_`  and `_ID_` 
 from `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/_BIG_BASE64_/edit#gid=_ID_` to your `curl`.  There are no `ccc`  and no  `key `  args at spreadsheets (plural).