# How to add a row to new Google Sheets in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, google-sheets

I am following [this blog article](http://mikeheavers.com/main/code-item/submitting_custom_form_data_to_a_google_spreadsheet_with_javascript). I need to implement a similar function using either PHP or JavaScript.

It appears that Google spreadsheet has changed to "Google Sheets", and the old way of appending is not supported anymore.

I have implemented a PHP solution to fetch the data from the the Google Sheet and extract the data as CSV data (from [New Google Spreadsheets publish limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189665/new-google-spreadsheets-publish-limitation)).

I need to add to this the ability to write a record to the spreadsheet. Can anyone provide a pointer to how this can be done using PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: Are there any API docs from Google on this? If there is an API I should think the docs would be quite good.

Comment: @https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_list_row , but I could not gather the URL from the docs

Comment: It says you have something called a "list feed", which contains a `link` element, and that in turn contains the post URL. Does that mean anything to you? I've never used Google Docs before.