# Importing data into R from google spreadsheet

Tags: r, google-sheets

There seems to be a change in the google spreadsheet publishing options. It is no longer possible to publish to the web as csv or tab file ([see this recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189665/new-google-spreadsheets-publish-limitation)). Thus the usual way to use RCurl to import data into R from a google spreadsheed does not work anymore:

```
require(RCurl)
u <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=en_GB&hl=en_GB&key=0AmFzIcfgCzGFdHQ0eEU0MWZWV200RjgtTXVMY1NoQVE&single=true&gid=4&output=csv"
tc <- getURL(u, ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
net <- read.csv(textConnection(tc))
```

Does anyone have a work-around?

Comment: It would probably help if you shared what you consider "the usual way". Also, I still seem to be able to publish to the web as a CSV with Google spreadsheet.

Comment: There is [gspreadr](https://github.com/jennybc/gspreadr): a package to ccess and manage Google spreadsheets from R

Comment: @Ben Great suggestion but note the package name has changed and is no `googlesheets` (https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets), also available on CRAN.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the [googlesheets4](https://cran.r-project.org/package=googlesheets4) package, a Google Sheets R API by Jenny Bryan.  It is the best way to analyze and edit Google Sheets data in R.  Not only can it pull data from Google Sheets, but you can edit the data in Google Sheets, create new sheets, etc.

The package can be installed with `install.packages("googlesheets4")`.

There's a [vignette](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/) for getting started; see [her GitHub repository](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4/issues) for more.  And you also can install the latest development version of the package from that GitHub page, if desired.

Comment: Please include some basic usage of the package in this answer

Comment: Just to save people a step in the future - it looks like the `googlesheets` package is being retired. [googlesheets4](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/) is its replacement.

Answer (score 61):

I just wrote a simple package to solve exactly this problem: downloading a Google sheet using just the URL.

```
install.packages('gsheet')
library(gsheet)
gsheet2tbl('docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I9mJsS5QnXF2TNNntTy-HrcdHmIF9wJ8ONYvEJTXSNo')
```

More detail is here: https://github.com/maxconway/gsheet

Comment: Good simple solutions

Comment: I like it because it is simple and it does not require auth just to view the sheet!

Answer (score 15):

I am working on a solution for this.  Here is a function that works on your data as well as a few of my own Google Spreadsheets.

First, we need a function to read from Google sheets. `readGoogleSheet()` will return a list of data frames, one for each table found on the Google sheet:

```
readGoogleSheet <- function(url, na.string="", header=TRUE){
  stopifnot(require(XML))
  # Suppress warnings because Google docs seems to have incomplete final line
  suppressWarnings({
    doc <- paste(readLines(url), collapse=" ")
  })
  if(nchar(doc) == 0) stop("No content found")
  htmlTable <- gsub("^.*?(<table.*</table).*$", "\\1>", doc)
  ret <- readHTMLTable(htmlTable, header=header, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.data.frame=TRUE)
  lapply(ret, function(x){ x[ x == na.string] <- NA; x})
}
```

Next, we need a function to clean the individual tables.  `cleanGoogleTable()` removes empty lines inserted by Google, removes the row names (if they exist) and allows you to skip empty lines before the table starts:

```
cleanGoogleTable <- function(dat, table=1, skip=0, ncols=NA, nrows=-1, header=TRUE, dropFirstCol=NA){
  if(!is.data.frame(dat)){
    dat <- dat[[table]]
  }

  if(is.na(dropFirstCol)) {
    firstCol <- na.omit(dat[[1]])
    if(all(firstCol == ".") || all(firstCol== as.character(seq_along(firstCol)))) {
      dat <- dat[, -1]
    }
  } else if(dropFirstCol) {
    dat <- dat[, -1]
  }

  if(skip > 0){
    dat <- dat[-seq_len(skip), ]
  }

  if(nrow(dat) == 1) return(dat)


  if(nrow(dat) >= 2){
    if(all(is.na(dat[2, ]))) dat <- dat[-2, ]
  }
  if(header && nrow(dat) > 1){
    header <- as.character(dat[1, ])
    names(dat) <- header
    dat <- dat[-1, ]
  }

  # Keep only desired columns
  if(!is.na(ncols)){
    ncols <- min(ncols, ncol(dat))
    dat <- dat[, seq_len(ncols)]
  }


  # Keep only desired rows
  if(nrows > 0){
    nrows <- min(nrows, nrow(dat))
    dat <- dat[seq_len(nrows), ]
  }

  # Rename rows
  rownames(dat) <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
  dat
}
```

Now we are ready to read you Google sheet:

```
> u <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0AmFzIcfgCzGFdHQ0eEU0MWZWV200RjgtTXVMY1NoQVE/pubhtml"
> g <- readGoogleSheet(u)
> cleanGoogleTable(g, table=1)


         2012-Jan Mobile internet Tanzania
1 Airtel Zantel Vodacom Tigo TTCL Combined


> cleanGoogleTable(g, table=2, skip=1)

                           BUNDLE       FEE VALIDITY     MB    Cost Sh/MB
1             Daily Bundle (20MB)     500/=    1 day     20     500  25.0
2            1 Day bundle (300MB)   3,000/=    1 day    300   3,000  10.0
3             Weekly bundle (3GB)  15,000/=   7 days  3,000  15,000   5.0
4            Monthly bundle (8GB)  70,000/=  30 days  8,000  70,000   8.8
5         Quarterly Bundle (24GB) 200,000/=  90 days 24,000 200,000   8.3
6            Yearly Bundle (96GB) 750,000/= 365 days 96,000 750,000   7.8
7 Handset Browsing Bundle(400 MB)   2,500/=  30 days    400   2,500   6.3
8                        STANDARD      <NA>     <NA>      1    <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Trying this out but getting a `Error in file(con, "r") (from #5) : cannot open the connection` any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: This code is now defunct.  Use the `googlesheets` package instead, as suggested by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if other use cases have a higher complexity or if something changed in the meantime. After publishing the spreadsheet in CSV format this simple 1-liner worked for me:

```
myCSV<-read.csv("http://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XKeAajiH47jAP0bPkCtS4OdOGTSsjleOXImDrFzxxZQ/pub?output=csv")
```

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)

Comment: this is the best answer, thanks a lot. Please note it works with this format too: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREEDSHEET_ID/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=NAME_OF_TAB so that you can select the tab you want(usefull with sheets with many tabs)

Answer (score 10):

There is an easiest way to fetch the google sheets even if you're behind the proxy

```
require(RCurl)
fileUrl <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[ID]/export?format=csv"
fileCSV <- getURL(fileUrl,.opts=list(ssl.verifypeer=FALSE))
fileCSVDF <-  read.csv(textConnection(fileCSV))
```

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way.

Be sure to match your URL carefully to the format of the example one here.  You can get all but the `/export?format=csv` piece from the Google Spreadsheets edit page.  Then, just manually add this piece to the URL and then use as shown here.

```
library(RCurl)
library(mosaic)
mydat2 <- fetchGoogle(paste0("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/",
  "1mAxpSTrjdFv1UrpxwDTpieVJP16R9vkSQrpHV8lVTA8/export?format=csv"))
mydat2
```

Answer (score 2):

Scrape the html table using httr and XML packages.

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

url <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12MK9EFmPww4Vw9P6BShmhOolH1C45Irz0jdzE0QR3hs/pubhtml"

readSpreadsheet <- function(url, sheet = 1){
  library(httr)
  r <- GET(url)
  html <- content(r)
  sheets <- readHTMLTable(html, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df <- sheets[[sheet]]
  dfClean <- function(df){
    nms <- t(df[1,])
    names(df) <- nms
    df <- df[-1,-1] 
    row.names(df) <- seq(1,nrow(df))
    df
  }
  dfClean(df)
}
df <- readSpreadsheet(url)
df
```

Comment: That gets me one row with 0 columns.

Comment: This works for me and is an efficient solution.  But I have an empty row below the header in the resulting data frame.

Comment: @hianalytics you should be able to tweak the dfClean function to match your the specific format of your spreadsheet

Comment: @jpmarindiaz Great, thank you! Adding this `df < df[-1,]` at the end of the script works great for me. I think the Google spreadsheet may have an issue since an extra row was added below the header after reading the data initially `readHTMLTable(...`

Comment: Correction: `df <- df[-1,]` And I also had the first row frozen in the Google Sheet which I believe was causing the extra blank row since it disappeared after I unfroze it then re-ran the original script @jpmarindiaz provided.

Answer (score 0):

Publish as CSV doesn't seem to be supported (or at least isn't *currently* supported) in the new Google Sheets, which is the default for any new sheet you create.  You can, though, create a sheet in the old Google Sheets format, which does support publish as CSV, through this link... https://g.co/oldsheets.

More details on the new vs. old Sheets is here... https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3541068?p=help_new_sheets&rd=1

Comment: @Andrie: I really like this solution and was stoked (especially after reading your blog post on this) since this is scalable and an easily reproducible workflow. BUT it didn't work and I receive this error `readGoogleSheet(gdoc)
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this solution! Works as good as the old one. I used another fix to get rid of the blank first line. When you just exclude it, you might per accident delete a valid observation when the line is 'unfreezed'. The extra instruction in the function deletes any rows which have no time stamp.

```
readSpreadsheet <- function(url, sheet = 1){
   library(httr)
   r <- GET(url)
   html <- content(r)
   sheets <- readHTMLTable(html, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   df <- sheets[[sheet]]
   dfClean <- function(df){
    nms <- t(df[1,])
    names(df) <- nms
    df <- df[-1,-1] 
    df <- df[df[,1] != "",]   ## only select rows with time stamps
    row.names(df) <- seq(1,nrow(df))
    df
   }
   dfClean(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still (as of May 2015) possible to get a CSV file out of Google Spreadsheets, using the hidden URL `<sheeturl>/export?format=csv` trick [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702001/3096626).

However, after solving this problem, one encounters another problem - numbers are formatted according to the locale of the sheet, e.g. you may get 1,234.15 in a "US" sheet or 1.234,15 in a "German" sheet. To decide on a sheet locale, go to File > Spreadsheet Settings in Google Docs.

Now you need to remove the decimal mark from the numeric columns so that R can parse them; depending on how large your numbers are, this may need to be done several times for each column. A simple function I wrote to accomplish this:

```
# helper function to load google sheet and adjust for thousands separator (,)
getGoogleDataset <- function(id) {
  download.file(paste0('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/', id, '/export?format=csv'),'google-ds.csv','curl');
  lines <- scan('google-ds.csv', character(0), sep="\n");

  pattern<-"\"([0-9]+),([0-9]+)";
  for (i in 0:length(lines)) {
    while (length(grep(pattern,lines[i]))> 0) {
      lines[i] <- gsub(pattern,"\"\\1\\2",lines[i]);
    }
  }
  return(read.csv(textConnection(lines)));
}
```

You will need to `require(utils)` and have curl installed, but no other extra packages.

Comment: You can use `format=tsv` instead. Into R `read.delim` with `dec = ","`.