# Fetch google sheets data and store into a data frame

Tags: r

I have a link to the [Google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M_S3iR5u7Ef5teNXWXVWH-EuokFNQ3Kd5dGt_T0YeH8/pubhtml):

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M_S3iR5u7Ef5teNXWXVWH-EuokFNQ3Kd5dGt_T0YeH8/pubhtml
```

I want to link this data directly with R and store it in a data frame .

Tried many things shared on the internet but nothing worked at all .

In fact here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873602/importing-data-into-r-from-google-spreadsheet) to the stackoverflow question, it is quite long and confusing and doesn't work in this case .

Any ideas  ?

Comment: use this package? https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets

Comment: "Tried many things" - please provide your attempts, so we don't have to repeat what you have already tried.

Comment: Agree with chinsoon12. googlesheets is available off CRAN repository. The basic usage are well-detailed at http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jennybc/googlesheets/master/vignettes/basic-usage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import the googlesheet as a data.frame in R:

```
# install.packages("googlesheets")
library("googlesheets")

GAP<-gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M_S3iR5u7Ef5teNXWXVWH-EuokFNQ3Kd5dGt_T0YeH8/pubhtml")

gs_browse(GAP)

dat2<-gs_read(dat,ws = 1, range="A1:C6")
```

The data frame is return as:

```
> dat2
Source: local data frame [5 x 3]

      A     B     V
  (int) (int) (int)
1     1     5     0
2     2     4     9
3     3     3     8
4     4     2     7
5     5     1     6
```