# Problem in downloading googlesheets in to R

Tags: r

When I attempt to read the contents of google spreadsheet using the command:

```
data <-read.csv("https://docs.google.com//spreadsheets//drive.google.com//drive//folders//1h6u8CoszxaMYkqCuOEkVSayfHVeOLg1u",fileEncoding="UTF-8").
```

R reports an error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt", encoding = fileEncoding) : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://docs.google.com//spreadsheets//drive.google.com//drive//folders//1h6u8CoszxaMYkqCuOEkVSayfHVeOLg1u'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt", encoding = fileEncoding) :
  cannot open URL 'https://docs.google.com//spreadsheets//drive.google.com//drive//folders//1h6u8CoszxaMYkqCuOEkVSayfHVeOLg1u': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing data into R from google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873602/importing-data-into-r-from-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a specific package for this to work:

```
#Install the required package
install.packages('googlesheets4')
#Load the required library 
library(googlesheets4)
```

Maybe additional help can be found here -> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/google-sheets-in-r