# Download Public Google Spreadsheet as CSV?

Tags: csv, download, google-docs

I have a spreadsheet, ex.:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qVnTw1Cwb2Ziwta_N0p-V4_ptD6-ZypDvCIrnryNFU/pubhtml
```

that I want to download as a CSV file. To do this, I believe I must download it from a link similar to this:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key={INSERT KEY HERE}&output=csv
```

But my question is, how do I go about getting the "key"?

Comment: The key is that random looking string in the URL.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I tried that and it did not work as intended. Perhaps it is a part of the random looking string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download unpublished Google spreadsheet as CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730712/download-unpublished-google-spreadsheet-as-csv)

Answer (score 11):

Append the `/export?format=csv` just after the document id in the URL.
So in your case, the URL should look like this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qVnTw1Cwb2Ziwta_N0p-V4_ptD6-ZypDvCIrnryNF/export?format=csv`

Of course, this must link to an existing sheet that is publicly shared (for viewing)

Comment: @Tessaracter It works fine, I just tested it. The URL above is just an example, replace the document ID by yours (and obviously you must have access to it).

Comment: No, it does not. I tried on [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSc_2y5N0I67wDU38DjDh35IZSIS30rQf7_NYZhtYYGU1jJYT6_kDx4YpF-qw0LSlGsBYP8pqM_a1Pd/pubhtml#). But [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/aymwjd/how_do_you_select_csv_output_for_individual/) solution works -  https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/aymwjd/how_do_you_select_csv_output_for_individual/

Comment: @Tessaracter can you share the URL that finally worked for you, I want to download the same sheet

Comment: In your case, you can have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189665/new-google-spreadsheets-publish-limitation